# MenuBar click item listener

Tags: vaadin, menubar

I got the class TopMenu which extends MenuBar vaadin component and I override method:
addItem - this method is use to add items - now I got other class where I create

```
TopMenu topMenu = TopMenu();
```

and add as a component

```
addComponent(topMenu)
```

I need add listener to topMenu like:

```
topMenu.addListener(ClickListener...){...}
```

and get the item to change his styleName/layout

I can't use item command, thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
topMenu.addItemListener(...) //instead of addListener
```